# Python, ordem crescente de numeros

Tags: python-3.x, lista, vector

Meu objetivo no código é imprimir uma ordem crescente de números inteiros. Por exemplo:
O usuário digita 2 números e eu quero que seja impresso a ordem crescente.

Ex.:

```
n1 = int(input('Digite um número')) #O usuário digitou 9
n2 = int(input('Digite outro')) #O usuário digitou 2

Lsta=[n1,n2]

#O que deve ser impresso é [2,9] nessa ordem(o menor primeiro e depois o maior)
```

Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Obs: Sou iniciante em python

Comment: Mas você quer criar uma lista com todos os números de 2 a 9  ou apenas uma representação matemática do intervalo, seja esta `[2,9]` ?

Comment: tipo digitar 4, 5 e 3 e imprimi-los em ordem crescente

Comment: Vlw gente, me ajudaram muito^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá! Sugiro utilizar a função sorted:

```
n1 = int(input('Digite um número ')) #O usuário digitou 9
n2 = int(input('Digite outro ')) #O usuário digitou 2

Lsta=[n1,n2]
print(sorted(Lsta))
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Edição:**

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) e o [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto), a função `sorted` por default ordena a lista do menor para o maior (e não de forma aleatória) e retorna o valor ordenado. No entando, essa função **não altera** a lista original.

Caso seja de seu interesse que a lista seja alterada, então a opção a ser utilizada é o método `sort()`, que modifica a lista e retorna `None`. Isso quer dizer que `print(Lsta.sort())` vai imprimir `None` e não a lista modificada.

Segue aqui um exemplo:

```
n1 = int(input('Digite um número '))
n2 = int(input('Digite outro '))
n3 = int(input('Digite outro ')) 
n4 = int(input('Digite outro '))
n5 = int(input('Digite outro '))

Lsta=[n1,n2,n3,n4,n5]
print('Essa é a lista original:',Lsta)
print('Essa é a lista com sorted():',sorted(Lsta))
print('Essa é a lista após o sorted():',Lsta)
print('Resultado usando Lsta.sort():',Lsta.sort())
print('Essa é a lista após o .sort():',Lsta)
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter ajudado! :)

Comment: ´-´  Obrigado.´-´